# jquery 'editable' plugin enable bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working with the jquery plugin "editable" for edit in place. I've been trying to make it so that only one element is editable at a time. So I've been disabling their edit-ability in the onEdit and re-enabling it after (cancel or submit). I was able to do this successfully, however, I've encountered what seems to be a bug in the plugin whenever I call (selector).editable('enable').

Whenever I call editable('enable') on an element (regardless of whether it was disabled temporarily or not) once that element is selected the content of the text area box has textarea and button tags for it's contents. So displayed inside the text area is

```
<textarea style="width: 991px; height: 58px;" class="test"></textarea>
<button>Save</button><button>Cancel</button>
```

Implying that the text area was wrapped in another set of tags. Has anyone come across this before? Or perhaps have a suggestion for solving the problem? Thanks very much for your time/help.

Comment: *note* the source of this plugin is http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same bug lately. Figured out the problem after some debugging.

Inside the plugin the `toEditable` function is responsible to make the element editable. It is bound to the event that you specify default for which is `click`.

The problem is that the plugin doesn't keep a check on how many times the event is triggered. So each time you click the element it calls the `toEditable` function and it attempts to append the editable html to the element.

This is the reason you are seeing that markup. Try changing event to double click and you will get a better understanding of what I am saying.

Regards,
SW